# C# - Force json conversion to always create arrays

Tags: c#, json

I need to serialize my xml into json before returning to the client. I am using:
json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument);

A problem is when an xml element "elem1" has a single child that is a folder then this child will be added to elem1 as an object rather than an array with one member. Is there a way of enforcing that?

Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you'd provide a short but complete example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Someone already posted a similar problem and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488662/json-net-xml-serialization-misunderstands-arrays) is the solution.

Comment: I looked at the attached link. Not sure how I can use the solution provided there because it does not show how to update all elements with row count = 1. I would expect some kind of recursion.