# Parse an XML to JSON with custom changes

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have a piece of code that generate an XML base of a "template" file, all the data is dynamically taken from the project, base on current user..

And what i need to do, is to send JSON structure string to an API (i have no control on).

The problem which i am facing is that i can't manage to generate such a JSON(in the right format) from the XML using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

With the help of an online tool i have creates this [XML](http://pastebin.com/Da4C3vit) from that [JSON](http://pastebin.com/AmkFYfSK), `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(XML)` generates a JSON, but instead, for example `element` that represent an array item - i need each item to be in `[]`, `RootDTO` the root element, i don't need it at all.

So what i need to accomplish is turning this [XML](http://pastebin.com/Da4C3vit) to a JSON that structured like that [JSON](http://pastebin.com/AmkFYfSK).

Is it possible with the use of "json.net"?
Do i need to write a "custom serilizer"

---

The XML i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootDTO>
   <destination>
      <name>companyName</name>
   </destination>
   <orderData>
      <amount>123.45</amount>     
      <items>
         <element>            
            <binding>saddle</binding>
            <components>
               <element>                            
                  <width>210</width>
               </element>
            </components>
            <description>Introductory x</description>         
         </element>
      </items>
   </orderData>
</RootDTO>
```

---

The JSON `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` produce

```
{
   "?xml": {
      "@version": "1.0",
      "@encoding": "UTF-8"
   },
   "RootDTO": {
      "destination": {
         "name": "companyName"
      },
      "orderData": {
         "amount": "123.45",
         "items": {
            "element": {
               "binding": "saddle",
               "components": {
                  "element": {
                     "width": "210"
                  }
               },
               "description": "Introductory x"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

The desired JSON

```
{
   "destination": {
     "name": "companyName"
   },
   "orderData": {
      "amount": "123.45",
      "items": [
         {
            "binding": "saddle",
            "components": [
               {
                 "width": "210"
               }
            ],
            "description": "Introductory x"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What do you mean? i posted the init XML and the desired JSON, what i am asking, is how to parse it.. with the use of JSON.NET or other? how can i explain it better?

Comment: this question has already been answered: [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-by-using-json-net)

Comment: This is the only trouble code `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(XML)` and the xml + json, this is the only thing that i have posted - a brief as i could for making it understandably

Comment: @Gerald V i know how to use JSON.NET, this is not the question- i want to customize the output

Comment: Are you parsing the XML into an object? If so, all you have to do is JSON that object.

Comment: [`XmlNodeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_XmlNodeConverter.htm) has properties [`DeserializeRootElementName`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_XmlNodeConverter_DeserializeRootElementName.htm) and [`OmitRootObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_XmlNodeConverter_OmitRootObject.htm) that may solve your *`RootDTO` the root element, i don't need it at all* issue.

Comment: But beyond that, can you show an example that is [as simple as possible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the XML you have, the JSON you are getting, and the JSON you want to get?  It's unclear just from your written question and your linked JSON and XML where your problem lies.

Comment: @dbc i updated my question

Comment: @EranMeir - the desired JSON in your question was invalid.  You can see the error if you upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  I made a plausible fix since the error seemed unrelated to your conversion problems.  If I fixed it wrongly, please update.

Answer (score 1):

You have a the following problems:

1. You don't want the root element.

   That's easily removed, use [`JsonConvert.SerializeXNode Method(XObject, Formatting, omitRootObject = true)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXNode_2.htm) or set [`XmlNodeConverter.OmitRootObject = true`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_XmlNodeConverter_OmitRootObject.htm).
2. Elements are not coming back as JSON arrays.

   There is a basic inconsistency between XML and JSON in that XML does not have the concept of an array.  It merely has sequences of elements with names.  So, under what circumstances does Json.NET create arrays?  From [Converting between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm):

   > Multiple nodes with the same name at the same level are grouped together into an array.

   However, what you have a two-level list, like so:

   ```
   <Container>
       <element>
       </element>
       <!-- Repeat as necessary -->
   </Container>
   ```

   Json.NET will not automatically recognize the container element as an array, thus you will need to pre-process the XML with [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) or post-process with [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).  I think the latter is easier.  Luckily, all your list entries are named `element` making the post-processing straightforward.  It can be done with the following two extension methods:

   ```
   public static class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static JObject ToJObject(this XDocument xDoc)
       {
           // Convert to Linq to XML JObject
           var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new XmlNodeConverter { OmitRootObject = true } } };
           var root = JObject.FromObject(xDoc, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));

           // Convert two-level lists with "element" nodes to arrays.
           var groups = root.Descendants()
               .OfType<JProperty>()
               .Where(p => p.Name == "element")
               .GroupBy(p => (JObject)p.Parent)
               .Where(g => g.Key.Parent != null && g.Key.Properties().Count() == g.Count())
               .ToList();
           foreach (var g in groups)
           {
               // Remove values from properties to prevent cloning
               var values = g.Select(p => p.Value)
                   .SelectMany(v => v.Type == JTokenType.Array ? v.Children().AsEnumerable() : new[] { v })
                   .ToList()
                   .Select(v => v.RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent());
               g.Key.Replace(new JArray(values));
           }
           return root;
       }

       public static JToken RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent(this JToken node)
       {
           if (node == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("node");
           var contained = node.AncestorsAndSelf().Where(t => t.Parent is JContainer && t.Parent.Type != JTokenType.Property).FirstOrDefault();
           if (contained != null)
               contained.Remove();
           // Also detach the node from its immediate containing property -- Remove() does not do this even though it seems like it should
           if (node.Parent is JProperty)
               ((JProperty)node.Parent).Value = null;
           return node;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then just do:

   ```
       var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
       var root = xDoc.ToJObject();
       var jsonString = root.ToString();
   ```

Comment: Thanks @dbc - regarding the array that is not being created from XML->JSON, i encountered this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488662/json-net-xml-serialization-misunderstands-arrays) it seems that if implement  that solution, what left to do is to delete the `<elment>` tag, it's seems like it's more straightforward solution.. Can you give your opinion on this?